# Azure DevOps exclusive release on environment

Tags: azure-devops

How can I achieve the exclusive release on specific environment?

I have few release pipelines. Each of them can release code, in the first stage, and then, on another stage, run e2e UI tests on given environment.
The code release during tests in progress on another stage/pipeline can lead to exception.

I need to sync releases on the same environment or rather block any new pipeline execution (code or test) if any test stage is in progress.

Currently we are using Azure Hosted agents and we have one per environment and force release on those. This is not too effective. We are aiming toward our own VM Scale Set.

Any ideas?